# Input file not passed to asp.net core using form

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am having form like this:

```
<form action="/Art/Add" type="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ddd" value="testttt" />
    <input type="file" name="files" />
    <button>Add</button>
</form>
```

Then i submit file to it and submit form and header looks something like this (it has more data than shown here) [image: problem]

And here is the server side code:

```
[Route("/Art/Add")]
public IActionResult Add(TempArtClass artModel)
{
    JsonResult t = base.ImageUpload(artModel.files).Result as JsonResult;
    string[] fullFilePathsReturned = t.Value as string[];

    User<UserCustomProperties> cu = Request.GetUser();

    if (cu == null)
        return View("Error", "You do not have permission to add new art!");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(artModel.art.Name))
        return View("Error", "You must enter name!");

    if (artModel.art.Name.Length > 32)
        return View("Error", "Name must not exceed 32px!");

    Art<ArtInformation>.Add(artModel.art.Name, cu.ID, artModel.art.Price, artModel.art.Details, artModel.art.VAT, fullFilePathsReturned[0], artModel.art.Type, artModel.art.Tag);

    return Redirect("/" + cu.Name + "/a/" + artModel.art.Name);
}
```

TempArtClass is this:

```
public class TempArtClass
{
    public Art<ArtInformation> art { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> files { get; set; }
    public string ddd { get; set; }
}
```

and when i debug `ddd` has value, `art` class has value but my `files` is null.... I also tried adding `multiple` to html tag `<input>` but it is not working.

Comment: you should use enctype attribute with "multipart/form-data" inside your form tag. it allows entire files to be included in the data. here are some details 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean"

Comment: @SyedMunisAli Yea, that was the problem...

Comment: solved questions should be marked as answered.